# Microsoft SQL Server 2014: Incorrect Generated Script Ordering when Export Self-Referenced Table to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a question regarding the data script generation tools in SQL Server.

I have a table which contains a column `parentId` referencing the `id` of its parent. In other words, this table is self-referencing. When I generate data script for this table (using Task -> Generate Scripts), the SQL generated in incorrect order.

It seems that the generated script is in alphabetical order of column id but ignoring the self-referenced foreign key.

Schema for the table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
  [id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [parentId] [nvarchar](50) NULL

  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([id] ASC) 
                  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_MyTable] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([parentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MyTable] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_MyTable]
GO
```

Incorrectly generated data script

```
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([id], [parentId]) VALUES (N'AAA', N'BBB')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([id], [parentId]) VALUES (N'BBB', NULL)
```

I want to generate data script in correct execution order i.e. those data script containing important id must go first before their id can be used as the `parentId` in other data script. I really find no way to configure SQL Server and I find no solution despite searching through the net for a week.

Please help!!

Comment: Just disable the foreign key constraint, perform the inserts, and then re-enable the foreign key constraint. (In SQL Server, you can disable the foreign key constraint with the NOCHECK option.)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175041(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: But is there any way to make sure generating those data script respecting the self-reference key but not alphabetical order of primary key?

Comment: Is there a way? Yes. You could write your own extract routine that runs a query to retrieve the rows and output INSERT statements in the desired order.

Comment: How to write the extract routine? Could you mind explain more about not detail? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind that for a general solution, you'd need to anticipate circular references... rows that reference each other. As a simple example of that, for the table demonstrated in the question, consider what order these rows would need to be inserted: `('AAA','BBB')`,`('BBB','CCC')`, `('CCC','AAA')`.

Comment: Extracting rows "in order" would work for only a subset of cases. That's why the more general solution to foreign key constraints and the "order of inserts" problem is deferred constraint checking. My initial comment stands... in SQL Server, emulate a deferrable constraint by disabling the foreign key check, performing the inserts, and then re-enabling the constraint.  As far as the question you asked... how to get the "data script generation tools" to produce the result you are looking for, my guess is it's not a supported feature.